# Mac LaunchAgent with full disk access and caffeinate

Tags: macos, permissions, scheduled-tasks, launchd, sleep-mode

I have a script that I would like to run every day at 4 AM. It downloads data to my user folder, fits some models, and saves files within my user directory. The script is a shell script, with one Python command, followed by an R command (with Rscript), and is stored in `/Library/Scripts/`. It has execute permissions. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd "/Users/myusername/Desktop/my/dir/with/data";

/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 download_data.py;

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/bin/Rscript fitModels.R;
```

Here is my .plist file, which is stored in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` and was loaded with `launchctl`. `fdautil` is a utility that allows scripts called from within LaunchAgents to be granted full disk access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.myscript</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/fdautil</string>
        <string>exec</string>
        <string>/Library/Scripts/myscript.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
          <key>Hour</key>
          <integer>4</integer>
          <key>Minute</key>
          <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have also changed the setting in System Preferences to automatically wake my computer at 3:58 AM. This setup "works," except for the fact the computer goes to sleep within a few minutes after the script starts, so the script does not complete.

If I were running this script manually, I would fix this issue with `caffeinate`. Yet if I add `<string>caffeinate</string>` as the first `ProgramArgument`, that seems to nullify the behavior of `fdautil`, meaning the Python and R scripts aren't able to be executed due to permissions issues. If I add it as the third program argument (after `exec`), and reference it via its full path `/usr/bin/caffeinate`, I see `You don't have permission to run this command via fdautil`.

If instead I prepend `caffeinate` to each line in the shell script itself, the Python portion runs fine, but the R script fails in the middle of loading packages with `zsh: killed     caffeinate  fitModels.R` (the script runs fine without `caffeinate`, getting an explanation for this issue is probably its own question).

How can I set up this LaunchAgent to ensure that the script runs as intended, and my computer stays awake for long enough to allow it to complete?

The only alternative I can think of is to just set up another `LaunchAgent` that calls `caffeinate -t` at 4 AM and pick a long enough time such that the other script is guaranteed to finish in that time. Yet the runtime of my script can vary significantly day-to-day, and this feels like a "hacky" solution.

Comment: Why don't you just disable automatic sleeping by going to the "Energy Saver" settings and turn on "Prevent automatic sleeping when the display is off"? That's what I do for my primary server which runs things (e.g., security camera image capture, a publicly visible web server) which I want to run 24x7.

Comment: I'd rather allow the computer to sleep when it can/should, but you're right, this might have to be the solution